# Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop startup with no monitor

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, vnc

I'm rather new to Linux - this is why I choose Ubuntu desktop as the most comfortable one to my learning experience.

After installing Ubuntu 16.04 desktop - If I try and connect via TightVNC - everything works great.
the problem is when I put the computer in another room and start it (No monitor connected) - nothing happens and cant connect.
If I plug my monitor at this stage - All I get is a black screen with no options other than hard-restarting the computer. (it comes up properly when the monitor is connected).

I've tried searching for a solution for the last few days - Even trying to install Ubuntu SERVER (but then my WiFi is not auto-detected like in the desktop version - and I couldn't find how to do THAT)

I reinstalled Ubuntu desktop - and tried changing something in the grub file regarding 'nomode' - this didn't work either. (Only difference is - I couldn't load the system even with monitor connected and had to use recovery mode to restore my backed-up grub file.)

Its important to state I need nvidia drivers installed on the system so no way i can use dummy drivers.

All I want is the system to boot, reach the desktop and let me connect via VNC.
This is real easy in Windows and im rather surprised by the complexity of the matter.

Thanks in advance,

**EDIT: sorry if it wasnt clear - I just want to system to boot up and reach the desktop without an actual monitor connected to it.**

For some reason this is marked as duplicate - I've gone over GRUB options on all its forms from people who answered those - but they wont work for me. (as explained in the post itself) so is changing the xorg.conf file - I dont think I have that installed - I am using ubuntu's native "share desktop" option

Dummy plug is not an option since no one in ebay sends to where I am.

Comment: Errrmm... so what's your actual question?

Comment: Sorry if it wasnt clear. - How can i make Ubuntu desktop boot up without an actual monitor connected to it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe installing `xrdp` you can connect from otrher computers, using Remote Desktop in Windows or Remote Dsktop for Mac by Microsoft or RemminaLinux.